# Android Volley multiple POST to server

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using Volley into an android app that sends coordinates from tablet to my server. 
When network connection goes down, the app stores data into an SQlite DB on the device and when JobScheduler finds again the connection, this method in the sequel, sends the records not still synced to the server.

```
private void saveCoordinate(final String android_id, final String latitude, final String longitude, final String timestamp) {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, MainActivity.URL_SAVE_COORDINATE,

                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                            if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                                // delete the synced sign row
                                db.deleteSyncedCoordinate(timestamp);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("android_id", android_id);
                params.put("latitude", latitude);
                params.put("longitude", longitude);
                params.put("timestamp", timestamp);

                return params;
            }
        };

        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

This is the the same method that works with network connection and normal send, a part from the fact that it deletes record when they have been synced and it does nothing when the send fails. 
I have tested the app, in a lot of time and trip, and appears that there are multiple send of coordinates. Sometimes two send, sometimes three, it isn't a regular bug but on, for example, 30 coordinates saved on SQlite and, when connection comes back, sent to server, 3 of the data presents multiple record on the DB.

I've tried to set a Retry Policy, like in the previous code, or connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0) (that are both solution from other Stackoverflow questions) but it doesn't solve the problem.

Can you help me? I can provide other code parts or info if you need. 
Thanks in advance.